# Change pandas file for read_excel in bokeh callback?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I've got a working `bokeh dashboard` with line plots that read from a `pandas df` via `read_excel`. What I want is to use a `RadioButtonGroup` to change the filename - based on the active button value - in order to read a new dataset.

I'm assuming it it achieved by some sort of callback but I can't seem to work out what that is; it's worth noting I know very little about `JS` so `CustomJS` is new to me.

For example:

I have two files: **a.xlsx** and **b.xlsx**

```
graphs = ['a', 'b']

file = '%s.xlsx' %(presumably graphs list index)

button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=graphs, active=0)
```

And so what I want is:

if active radio button is `a` then pass this into `pd.read_excel` and therefore read `a.xlsx`, if active radio button is `b` then pass this into `pd.read_excel` and so on...

All the files are the same format so literally the only difference between the files is the name.

I have tried looking into changing source data via `ColumnDataSource` but they mostly change the actual data with a `CustomJS` and `source.data.emit()` as opposed to loading new data in.

Comment: better show `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and test it.

Comment: The rest of the code is irrelevant really. It just needs excel files to read with arbitrary data for a line plot, otherwise the remaining code is purely styling.

Comment: without rest of code we would have to write all from scratch to show how to use it. Better create `minimal working code`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.